# How to add a texture with visual studio 2010 (XNA)

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so till today I've used visual studio 2008 with XNA 3.1
I decided to get updated and to install visual studio 2010 with XNA 4.0,
When I had to add a reference(any texture e.g .bmp, .jpg) I just had to do right click in the content and add reference, now I have some problem on adding a refernce of that kind.
Anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add existing item should work fine.

Comment: Content -> Add -> Existing Item.

Comment: Also now content are separate projects so you need to create a content project. Then you can use them as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

You could always justd drag and drop, keep in mind it will copy things to the root content folder if you're copying from outside the content folder.